# Easiest way to truncate / trim last character in a file

Tags: java, trim, truncate

What is the most simple way to delete the last character in a file in Java?

Comment: [FileChannel.truncate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#truncate(long))

Comment: Do you really mean the very last character of the entire file, or do you mean the last char of each line?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FileChannel truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#truncate%28long%29):

```
try {
    File file = new File("fileToTruncate");
    FileChannel fileChannel = new FileOutputStream(file, true).getChannel();
    fileChannel.truncate(fileChannel.size() - 1); //Removes last character
    fileChannel.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

}
catch (IOException ex) {

}
```

Comment: Reading the entire file into memory isn't very efficient; what if the file's size is, say, 1 GB?  Your code is functionally correct but would place significant demands on the system.

Comment: @VGR which method here reads the entire file into memory?

Comment: @SergiyDakhniy The answer has been edited since my comment.

Comment: @VGR Oh, got it. Thanks!